# Client side: Subscribing to multiple websocket pushing from different server

Tags: javascript, websocket, stomp, spring-websocket, sockjs

I am new to SockJS, Stomp and Spring websocket.
I have spring websocket configuration like below:

```
@Override
public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
    registry.addEndpoint("/stomp-endpoint").setAllowedOriginPatterns("*").setAllowedOrigins().withSockJS();
}

@Override
public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
    registry.enableSimpleBroker("/topic", "/queue");  
    registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
}
```

I am running multiple instances or deployment of above implementation in my `spring` applications.
When I access it locally, below code on client side JS works perfect:

```
var socket = new SockJS("/stomp-endpoint");
stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
stompClient.connect("", "", function (frame) {
        stompClient.subscribe("/topic/publish-updates", function (publishedUpdates) {
                            showMessages(JSON.parse(publishedUpdates.body));
        });
    });
```

Now, I want something like below, so that my single UI code will fetch push notifications from two servers.

```
var socket1 = new SockJS("http://cml-consumerinstance-ci-0000.com:8080/stomp-endpoint");
stompClient1 = Stomp.over(socket);
stompClient1.connect("", "", function (frame) {
        stompClient1.subscribe("http://cml-consumerinstance-ci-0000.com:8080/topic/publish-updates", function (publishedUpdates) {
                            showMessages(JSON.parse(publishedUpdates.body));
        });
    });

var socket2 = new SockJS("http://cml-consumerinstance-ci-1111.com:8080/stomp-endpoint");
stompClient2 = Stomp.over(socket);
stompClient2.connect("", "", function (frame) {
        stompClient2.subscribe("http://cml-consumerinstance-ci-1111.com:8080/topic/publish-updates", function (publishedUpdates) {
                            showMessages(JSON.parse(publishedUpdates.body));
        });
    });
```

Above code doesn't work.
I tried with `"http://cml-consumerinstance-ci-0000.dev3oke2phx.databasede3phx.oraclevcn.com:8080/app/topic/publish-updates"` also.

Could someone please help me, how to achieve multiple subscription from different servers?

Answer (score 0):

You should subscribe `/topic/publish-updates`, not `http://cml-consumerinstance-ci-1111.com:8080/topic/publish-updates`.